# You are a cat. How do you swap?

Tags: logical-deduction

Number twenty-one cages containing mice, 1, 2, 3, etc., up to 21, and place them in the following order:

```
1 14 15 17 3 7 13 6 20 2 19 21 5 18 8 11 16 9 12 4 10
```

- You start from a cage of your choice, calling that cage *one*, and count, *one, two, three, etc.,* from left to right. Once you reach the end, you continue counting from the leftmost cage.
- When your count matches with the number on the cage, you have made a ***catch***, and you can eat that mouse <sup><sub>(you're a cat)</sub></sup>, and throw away the cage.
- Then start at the cage next to it <sup><sub>(or the leftmost cage, if you just caught the rightmost cage)</sub></sup>, call that *one*, and try to make another catch, and so on.

Let's say you start at **18**, calling that cage *one*, your first catch will be **19**.

```
1 14 15 17 3 7 13 6 20 2 19 21 5 18 8 11 16 9 12 4 10 
                                 ^
```

Remove **19** and your next catch will be **10**.

```
1 14 15 17 3 7 13 6 20 2    21 5 18 8 11 16 9 12 4 10 
                            ^
```

Remove 10 and your next catch is **1**.

```
1 14 15 17 3 7 13 6 20 2    21 5 18 8 11 16 9 12 4  
^
```

Remove the 1, and you **cannot make another catch, even if you count up to 21**.

```
  14 15 17 3 7 13 6 20 2    21 5 18 8 11 16 9 12 4  
  ^
```

Since you're very hungry, **you want to catch all the twenty-one mice**. But you'll soon figure out that this is not here possible - no matter which cage you start from.

But here's what you can do:

> You can choose **two** cages and swap them before you begin. Then, if you start at the right place, you might be able to catch all twenty-one mice.

- You may never pass over a catch, i.e., you must always eat the mouse you caught, remove that cage and continue.
- You can always count up to 21, even if fewer cages are left.

#### What two cages would you swap, and which cage would you start counting from?

---

<sup>It would be great if you could include the strategy you used to get to the answer, unless you used brute force.</sup>

Comment: I didn't realize you can count higher than the amount of cages. You may want to mention that in the question.

Comment: [Updated](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/399/2). I hope its clearer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I employed a brute force strategy, testing every possible swap with every possible starting position. I used the following Python code (Python 2.7):

```
cages = map(int, '1 14 15 17 3 7 13 6 20 2 19 21 5 18 8 11 16 9 12 4 10'.split())

swaps = ((i,j) for i in xrange(len(cages)) for j in xrange(len(cages)) if i > j)

for (i,j) in swaps:
    for start in xrange(len(cages)):
        l = list(cages)
        l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]  # perform the swap
        pos = start
        count = 1

        while (count <= 21) and l:
            if l[pos] == count:
                del l[pos]
                count = 0
            else:
                pos += 1

            if pos >= len(l):
                pos = 0

            count += 1

        if not l:  # if the list is empty, we've found one that works
            print 'swap', cages[i], 'with', cages[j], 'and start at', cages[start]
```

which produces the following output:

> swap 6 with 13 and start at 14
> swap 8 with 6 and start at 19
> swap 10 with 14 and start at 16

Comment: Yes, those are the three solutions to the problem. However, I would prefer an answer that does not use brute force over this one. If I don't find any, I shall accept this.

Comment: @JohnBupit I would also prefer such an answer. :)